Newline after theorem
I am writing a document which contains solutions for exercises from a mathematics textbook. The exercises are usually split up into separate parts and sometimes there is an introductory text before them. Currently, there is no newline at the start of the problem and solution statements. This looks bad, in particular in conjunction with the enumerate-environment. Therefore, I would like to have a newline at the start of each problem and solution statement. I would like this newline to have the vertical length of a paragraph break. I would also like to only add code to the preamble of the document and to not change anything to the main body of the code. How can I achieve this?
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headformat=\NAME,
  headpunct={}
]{mystyle}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\HelperDeclareTheorem}[4]{
  \declaretheorem[
    name=#3,
    refname={#1, #2},
    Refname={#3, #4},
    style=mystyle,
    postheadhook={\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{#3}}
  ]{#1}
}
\makeatother
\HelperDeclareTheorem{problem}{problems}{Problem}{Problems}
\HelperDeclareTheorem{solution}{solutions}{Solution}{Solutions}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
This introduces the problem.
\begin{enumerate}
\item {
This is the first part of the problem.
}
\item {
This is the second part of the problem.
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{problem}

\begin{solution}
\begin{enumerate}
\item {
This solves the first part of the problem.
}
\item {
This solves the second part of the problem.
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{solution}

\end{document}


This problem seems to be incredibly common. Yes, all of the following questions are really about this problem. Related questions:

Theorem environment - line break after label [closed]

Declaretheoremstyle headpostspace = \newline + indent?

Is it possible to skip the first line in a theorem environment?

Skipping line after "Proof" in proof environment

Enumerate alignment problem in theorem environment

Theorem environment with a line break after label and before an enumerate environment [closed]

Newline after theorem doesn't work if it starts with \begin{enumerate}

The statement of a theorem appearing on a new line

Line break after definition

Itemizing theorem body

Theorem environment : interaction with enumerate/itemize

Theorem formatting: strange interaction with itemize



Unrelated: \item does not take an argument.

@campa I usually write it like this since I find it easier to read. Is it bad practice to place the unnecessary braces?

You'll get lucky most of the time; however, I recall questions on this site where the braces were having side effects (I don't quite remember the reason, though).

Here is my own solution:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headformat=\NAME,
  headpunct={}
]{mystyle}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\HelperDeclareTheorem}[4]{
  \declaretheorem[
    name=#3,
    refname={#1, #2},
    Refname={#3, #4},
    style=mystyle,
    postheadhook={\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{#3}}
  ]{#1aux}
  \newenvironment{#1}{\begin{#1aux}\leavevmode\par}{\end{#1aux}}
}
\makeatother
\HelperDeclareTheorem{problem}{problems}{Problem}{Problems}
\HelperDeclareTheorem{solution}{solutions}{Solution}{Solutions}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
This introduces the problem.
\begin{enumerate}
\item {
This is the first part of the problem.
}
\item {
This is the second part of the problem.
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{problem}

\begin{solution}
This introduces the solution to the problem.
\begin{enumerate}
\item {
This solves the first part of the problem.
}
\item {
This solves the second part of the problem.
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{solution}

\begin{problem}
\begin{enumerate}
\item {
This is the first part of the problem.
}
\item {
This is the second part of the problem.
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{problem}

\begin{solution}
\begin{enumerate}
\item {
This solves the first part of the problem.
}
\item {
This solves the second part of the problem.
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{solution}

\end{document}



Hope the below MWE will meet your requirement.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headformat=\NAME,
  headpunct={}
]{mystyle}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\HelperDeclareTheorem}[4]{
  \declaretheorem[
    name=#3,
    refname={#1, #2},
    Refname={#3, #4},
    style=mystyle,
    postheadhook={\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{#3}}
  ]{#1}
}
\HelperDeclareTheorem{problem}{problems}{Problem}{Problems}
\HelperDeclareTheorem{solution}{solutions}{Solution}{Solutions}
\apptocmd{\problem}{\parindent\z@\protect\leavevmode\par\medskip}{}{}%
\apptocmd{\solution}{\protect\leavevmode}{}{}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{problem}%
This introduces the problem.
\begin{enumerate}
\item {
This is the first part of the problem.
}
\item {
This is the second part of the problem.
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{problem}

\begin{solution}
\begin{enumerate}
\item {
This solves the first part of the problem.
}
\item {
This solves the second part of the problem.
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{solution}

\end{document}


Edit
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headformat=\NAME,
  headpunct={}
]{mystyle}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\HelperDeclareTheorem}[4]{
  \declaretheorem[
    name=#3,
    refname={#1, #2},
    Refname={#3, #4},
    style=mystyle,
    postheadhook={\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{#3}}
  ]{#1}
}
\HelperDeclareTheorem{problem}{problems}{Problem}{Problems}
\HelperDeclareTheorem{solution}{solutions}{Solution}{Solutions}
\apptocmd{\problem}{\parindent\z@\protect\leavevmode\par\medskip}{}{}%
\apptocmd{\solution}{\parindent\z@\protect\leavevmode\par\medskip}{}{}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{problem}%
This introduces the problem.
\begin{enumerate}
\item {
This is the first part of the problem.
}
\item {
This is the second part of the problem.
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{problem}

\begin{solution}%
This introduces the solution to the problem.
\begin{enumerate}
\item {
This solves the first part of the problem.
}
\item {
This solves the second part of the problem.
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{solution}

\begin{problem}%
\begin{enumerate}\vspace{-1\topsep}
\item {
This is the first part of the problem.
}
\item {
This is the second part of the problem.
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{problem}

\begin{solution}%
\begin{enumerate}\vspace{-1\topsep}
\item {
This solves the first part of the problem.
}
\item {
This solves the second part of the problem.
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{solution}

\end{document}


Please include \vspace{-1\topsep} if a number list starts immediately after the head Problem/Solution, but this is not the proper method, but it will works.

This looks promising. Could you also add a newline at the start of the problem statements?

Updated, please check

Thank you. I would really prefer it if the vertical break had the vertical length of a paragraph break (\par). Is this also possible?

Do you mean some vertical space need after the head Problem?, sorry if I understand in a wrong way, please confirm

Yes, I would like there to be vertical space in the length of a \par between "Problem" and "This introduces the problem." as well as between "Solution" and "1. This solves the first part of the problem.". Your current solution almost achieves this, except for the fact that I would like for the vertical space to be larger.

\z@ is giving me an undefined control sequence error.

Sorry, updated, please check now

Thank you for the effort. This is almost perfect. However, some of the problem statements do not have an introductory line and immediately begin with an enumerate-environment. On the other hand, some solution statements also have an introductory line. In these cases, the solution either still has no vertical space or too much vertical space. I have added a MWE to my question that explains what I mean.

Shall I go with based on asmthm suggestion ?

I don't know what you mean by "amsthm suggestion" unfortunately.

Thanks, this is perfect. I will wait a bit before I accept the answer to see if anyone has a "proper" solution.

Again, thanks for your solution. I have added my own solution, based on your usage of \leavevmode\par.

@Smiley1000 Glad to hear, thanks for your complement.
